# A question in the proof of Rao-Blackwell theorem

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

This could be a naive question but I am just puzzled. I am learning the following proof of Rao-Blackwell theorem but **get puzzled by the equation in the *red box***. **Why the two expectations can be reduced to one expectation**? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an application of the [law of total expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).

Comment: That is what I need. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you also know, where in the proof the sufficiency of T is used? Which equality wouldn't hold if T wasn't a sufficient statistic?

Comment: The sufficiency of T actually isn't used here; the result is still true without that assumption. However, the sufficiency implies that $\theta^*$ is a function of the data (i.e., $X$), meaning it does not depend on the unknown parameter $\theta$. Without that, $\theta^*$ would not be a statistic, i.e. it couldn't be computed based on the data, hence it wouldn't be of any practical use in estimating $\theta$.